# Turning a Model to face the camera in C++/OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to turn a model I am drawing using c++ and openGL. I can get it to run at the camera, but have it face the camera is a different story. I do not want it to ALWAYS face the camera, just to face it while it is running.

I have a normalized vector that tells me where the Model is currently looking(direction). When I calculate the angle between the model's position and the camera position the angle seems to flux widely causing the model to turn in all sets of directions even when the camera remains still. I also tried to get the angle of its current direction it is facing and the direction of the camera but that didn't work either.

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
vec3 ModelPosition=model->getPosition();
vec3 CurrentModelDirection =model->getDirection();

vec3 CameraPosition=camera->getPosition();

vec3 directionToPlayer = CameraPosition-ModelPosition;
directionToPlayer =glm::normalize(directionToPlayer);

float deltaz = CurrentModelDirection .z-directionToPlayer .z;
float deltax = CurrentModelDirection .x-directionToPlayer .x;

float angle=glm::atan(deltaz,deltax) * (180.0f/3.14f);
model->setYaw(angle);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the target yaw angle should only depend on the `ModelPosition` (relative to the camera position) and not on the `CurrentModelDirection`.